# class not found 'package_modeule_Block_Adminhtml_About' in Magento_dir/includes/src/__default.php on line 28651

Tags: magento-1.9, php, module, extensions

I installed a Apptrian ImageOptimizer plugin for image optimization. After successful install when i go to configuration, below given error is showing.

Problem is `falat error: class not found 'package_modeule_Block_Adminhtml_About' in Magento_dir/includes/src/__default.php on line 28651`

I checked and found About.php in the path. 
I researched and found this may be the case if this class is not declared in `/etc/config.xml`. How to declare it?

Comment: your Question is not clear please ask clear question. and provide us code what you tried so far

Comment: check now. Question may clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have compiler enabled thus you need to recompile under **System > Tools > Compilation** in order to make the new modules working.

Comment: Thanks dude. I can not up vote for you. It worked.I will accept answer after 5 min.